# Unable to build a Q# program in VS Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, q#

I am new to quantum computing and have just installed Microsoft's Visual Studio Code and the QDK extension for it. However, when I try to build and run (dotnet run from the terminal), it is unable to give me an output for it and throws a few errors regarding namespace despite installing the extension (quantum sdk). I'm most likely doing something stupid so please point me in the right direction

My program is:

```
namespace helloqworld {

    open Microsoft.Quantum.Canon;
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Intrinsic;


    @EntryPoint()
    operation HelloQ() : Unit {
        Message("Hello quantum world!");
    }
}
```

And I get the following errors:

```
No namespace with the name "Microsoft.Quantum.Canon" exists.
No namespace with the name "Microsoft.Quantum.Intrinsic" exists.
{
    "resource": "/Users/nalini/Desktop/helloqworld/Program.qs",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
    "code": "QS6005",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "No type with the name \"EntryPoint\" exists in any of the open namespaces.",
    "source": "/Users/nalini/Desktop/helloqworld/Program.qs",
    "startLineNumber": 9,
    "startColumn": 6,
    "endLineNumber": 9,
    "endColumn": 16
}
{
    "resource": "/Users/nalini/Desktop/helloqworld/Program.qs",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
    "code": "QS5022",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "No identifier with the name \"Message\" exists.",
    "source": "/Users/nalini/Desktop/helloqworld/Program.qs",
    "startLineNumber": 11,
    "startColumn": 9,
    "endLineNumber": 11,
    "endColumn": 16
}
```

And my csproj file has:

```
Project Sdk="Microsoft.Quantum.Sdk/0.11.2004.2825">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your code build and run successfully if you just do `dotnet run` from terminal? If this is the case, this error comes from IntelliSense.

Are you using .NET Core 3.1.300? I think QDK release 0.11.2004.2825 has IntelliSense issues with .NET Core 3.1.300 specifically (the [relevant issue on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/qsharp-compiler/issues/434)), and downgrading .NET Core to 3.1.201 fixes this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today, fixed it by downloading the recent version of .NET by Microsoft from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet-framework
Make sure you'll download the right one for your processor.